# Can I set the wifi network so I do not have to choose it each time I log on?

Tags: wireless

I live in an apartment building with many wifi networks. Almost every time I log on I need to "choose from a hidden network" (or words to that effect) fo get to my network.  Can I bypass this step somehow?

Ubuntu 16.04
Wireless cards:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b5a7 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 1):

After you connected once, the network is saved by NetworkManager.

So, now just open up `nm-connection-editor`, double-click the name of your network *(a window with wifi configuration should pop up)*, then on tab `General` click checkbox `✓ Connect automatically`. Save the connection.

After reboot it should connect automatically, once the network is detected. Or, to use it ASAP, you can force NetworkManager to reload it with `nmcli con reload` command *(I don't know though if it's needed, it's possible that `nm-connection-editor` forces reload too)*.